# Getters/properties availability based on object's state (based on parsing state, for example)

Tags: java, oop, object, kotlin

Suppose that I have a parser that has internal states. One of which corresponds to full and successful parsing. The parser has fields that contain the results of the parsing. Fields should be available only with full and successful parsing. Otherwise, when accessing the field, an exception is thrown.

```
interface Parser {

    fun parse()
}

interface Data {

    val propertyA: String
}

class SimpleParser: Parser, Data {

    private var parserState = SimpleParserState.UNPARSED

    // property (getter), available only when state equals to PARSED_ALL (i.e. if parsing done successfully)
    private lateinit var _propertyA: String
    override val propertyA: String
        get() {
            if (parserState === SimpleParserState.PARSED_ALL) {
                return _propertyA
            }
            throw IllegalStateException("Parser's state is not PARSED_ALL. This property is unavailable")
        }

    override fun parse() {
        if (parserState !== SimpleParserState.UNPARSED) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Already parsed!")
        }
        // DO PARSING LOGIC
        _propertyA = "parsed string"
        parserState = SimpleParserState.PARSED_ALL
    }
}

enum class SimpleParserState {

    UNPARSED, PARSED_ALL, PARSED_PARTIAL, PARSED_NONE
}
```

Is this method correct when data and logic are stored in one object?
What other alternatives are there that fit the principles of OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: have the  `parse()` method return the parse result (instead of storing it in the parser's state).  That result could be an abstract class with two concrete subclasses: one for success (with getter(s) for the relevant result info) and one for failure (with getter(s) for the failure reason).